# Unrecognized selector sent to instance NSArrayM

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I'm new to IOS programming. Today i tried implementing UITabBarController, but decided to remove it. Ever since that my app crashes. I'm sure that i've removed the right part of the app delegate since i used ctrl + z. I cant really seem to find out where the app is crashing and why?

Sourcecode:

http://www.codeviewer.org/view/code:3cc0

debugging:

```
2014-02-24 21:00:26.628 app[1307:70b] -[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xca716d0
2014-02-24 21:00:26.631 app[1307:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xca716d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b235e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028a68b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02bc0903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02b1390b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x02b134ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   app                                 0x000627e9 -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] + 16057
6   UIKit                               0x01728318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
7   UIKit                               0x017285b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
8   UIKit                               0x01752ca9 -[UINavigationController rotatingSnapshotViewForWindow:] + 52
9   UIKit                               0x01a7ca60 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 420
10  UIKit                               0x016582f2 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1495
11  UIKit                               0x01657d16 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
12  UIKit                               0x01657be8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
13  UIKit                               0x01657c70 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
14  UIKit                               0x01656d0a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
15  UIKit                               0x01656c6c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
16  UIKit                               0x016579c3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
17  UIKit                               0x0165afb6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
18  UIKit                               0x0172c737 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
19  UIKit                               0x01650c1c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
20  UIKit                               0x01650d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
21  UIKit                               0x0165102d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
22  UIKit                               0x0165b89a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
23  app                                 0x00012ecf -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1391
24  UIKit                               0x0160e355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
25  UIKit                               0x0160eb95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
26  UIKit                               0x016133a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
27  UIKit                               0x0162787c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
28  UIKit                               0x01627de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
29  UIKit                               0x01615025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
30  GraphicsServices                    0x0448c2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
31  GraphicsServices                    0x0448be01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
32  CoreFoundation                      0x02a9ed65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
33  CoreFoundation                      0x02a9ea9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
34  CoreFoundation                      0x02ac977c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
35  CoreFoundation                      0x02ac8ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
36  CoreFoundation                      0x02ac88db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
37  UIKit                               0x01612add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
38  UIKit                               0x01614d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
39  app                                 0x0008f4fd main + 141
40  libdyld.dylib                       0x030c370d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Show your MenuViewController's `viewDidLoad` please.

Comment: Advice for the future: this sort of crash report is usually completely useless for people trying to help you debug your code. Its enough to give the type of error and the relevant code where the crash occurred. (In this case probably in the `MenuViewController` based on the crash report, as matt has already said)

Comment: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3cc0

 The source code.

Comment: Your code should be a part of your question, not linked to. If that link stopped working, then we would lose a relevant part of the question.

Comment: Google the message -- you will find thousands of answers -- hundreds here.  Study the message and understand what it's saying.  Study the exception traceback and understand that it usually points directly at the failing operation.  DEBUG the code, inserting NSLogs and setting breakpoints so you can observe what's happening.  DO YOUR HOMEWORK!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTextField unrecognized selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938750/nstextfield-unrecognized-selectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you removed `UITabBarController` also from your .xib file in Interface Builder?
Did you removed `UITabBarController` also from your .xib file in Interface Builder?
Check if object - in your case NSDictionary is kind of it's class and key is not null. For example:

```
- (void)fetchedDataAlerta:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSLog(@"RESP register %@", responseData);
    if(responseData ) { //here you have recieved valid info. Without it, next line  will crash
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

In your case

```
NSData* rawBody2 = [response2 rawBody];
//here check if NSData is not null, nil and is valid add line
if (rawBody2) {
    results2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawBody2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: i do not have a xib or storyboard. all is added programatically.